# Datatable.select doesn't return all columns in the main data table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am working with Datatable.select, in order to get some data. My code is the following:

```
for (int j=0; j<NStations.Count();j++)
{
    var result= DailyWeatherData.Select("StationName ='" + NStations[j]["StationName"] + "' and Monthh>='" + SP_Biofix.Month + "' and Monthh<='" + SP_DATE.Month + "'").CopyToDataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
    {
        WeatherData.ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

Then I ordered it using the following code :

```
WeatherData = WeatherData.AsEnumerable()
                         .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("StationName"))
                         .CopyToDataTable();
```

That gave me the following error:

> the column "stationName" does not belong to datatable.

Does this mean that I need to work with datatable.where ? Am I wrong in somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my question by replacing the following loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
   {
    WeatherData.ImportRow(row);
    }
```

with the following code :

```
 WeatherData.BeginLoadData(); 
                            WeatherData.Merge(result); 
                            WeatherData.EndLoadData();
```